# Droppable code called when just dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why the below alert gets fired when I drag an item over the droppable area ?

```
$(".all").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
       alert('should just fire when a item is dropped');
    }
}); 



$("li").draggable({
            connectToSortable : ".mySortable",
            helper : "clone",
            revert : "invalid",
            scroll: true,
            cursor: 'move'//,   
}
        });
```

Here is the line furthest up in the call stack that gets called :

```
jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
```

Which is contained in jquery-1.7.2.js

That line of code is within :

```
if ( !eventHandle ) {
            elemData.handle = eventHandle = function( e ) {
                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?


jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :

                    undefined;
            };
```

If you paste this code into the fiddle  -  jsfiddle.net/Xz3u2 it should re-create the error :

```
$(".all2").sortable({
            revert : true
        });
$(".all").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
       alert('should just fire when a item is dropped');
    }
}); 

$(".all2").draggable({
            connectToSortable : ".all2",
});​
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3u2/. Otherwise, there is not enough information.

Comment: Just a pointer - but you might need to reword you question - as it's quite difficult to work out what your asking... (Apologies if your English isn't great.. - but if you want to give some more detail in a comment, I'll happily re-word it for you :) )

Comment: can you post the .draggable call and some markup?

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet please see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3u2/2/

```
$(".all2").sortable({
            revert : true
        }).draggable();
$(".all").droppable({
    accept: '.all2',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
       alert('should just fire when a item is dropped');
    }
});
```

Comment: i have honestly experience with connectToSortable so i can't tell you the difference, only how I would do it..

Comment: Implementing the draggable separately shouldn't change the result. only that is better to perfomance, making use of $(selector) it's apparently expensive. check for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info